# Best practice for storing a device authentication token in node?

Tags: node.js, authentication, websocket

I have a node application that connects to some  hardware through a websocket (code below). Currently, here are the steps taken to connect and authenticate to the device:

The `node application` opens a websocket connection using a predetermined set of network parameters.

The device then sends a `pin number` back to the `node application`

That `pin number` has to by *physically* typed in on the device.

Once the node application is authenticated via the `pin number`, an authentication `token` is sent to the `node application`, which would allow users to bypass the pin authentication upon reconnect.

The `token` changes on every new websocket session, so the `token` needs to be updated in the `Node Application`.

This step is where my question is.

**How/Where should I store each new authentication token?**

Note the auth token part of the code is found at

```
CloverDeviceConfiguration.prototype.onPairingSuccess = function(authToken) {  
    console.log("Pairing succeeded, authToken is " + authToken);
};
```

Here is the full code

```
//Required libaries via npm
var clover = require('remote-pay-cloud');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest-ssl").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var log = clover.Logger.create();


var endpoint = "ws://192.168.1.65:5678/remote_pay"; // use the change endpoint function to change these paremeters as required. 
var isConnected = false;

/* Custom Functions Section
 *
 * Non predefined functions for communicating with the Clover device.
 *
 */

var changeEndpoint = function(socketType, ipaddress, port) {
    endpoint = socketType // ws or wss
        +
        "//" +
        ipaddress //ip address of the network pay display server (found on clover mini device)
        +
        ":" +
        port //port number of the network pay display (found on clover mini device)
        +
        "/remote_pay";
}

var paymentRequest = function(amount) {
    var saleRequest = new clover.remotepay.SaleRequest();
    saleRequest.setExternalId(clover.CloverID.getNewId());
    saleRequest.setAmount(amount);
    cloverConnector.sale(saleRequest);
}


var webSocketFactory = function() { // function required for connecting to clover device WITHOUT a web browser
    let webSocketOverrides = {
        createWebSocket: function() {
            // To support self-signed certificates you must pass rejectUnauthorized = false.
            // https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/ssl.js
            let sslOptions = {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            };
            // Use the ws library by default.
            return new WebSocket(endpoint, sslOptions);
        }
    }
    return Object.assign(new clover.CloverWebSocketInterface(endpoint), webSocketOverrides);
};

var toggleConnection = function() {

    if (!isConnected) {
        cloverConnector.initializeConnection();
        var connectorListener = new CloverConnectorListener(cloverConnector);
        cloverConnector.addCloverConnectorListener(connectorListener);
        CloverConnectorListener.prototype = Object.create(clover.remotepay.ICloverConnectorListener.prototype);
        CloverConnectorListener.prototype.constructor = CloverConnectorListener;
    } else {
        cloverConnector.dispose();
        isConnected = false;
    }
}

// End Custom Functions


/* Clover Device Configuration/Connection Section
 *
 *
 */

var CloverDeviceConfiguration = function() {  
    clover.WebSocketPairedCloverDeviceConfiguration.call(this,       "ws://192.168.1.65:5678/remote_pay", // endpoint
              "com.cloverconnector.javascript.simple.sample:1.4", // Application Id
              "Javascript Simple Sample", // posName

              "Register_1", // serialNumber

              null, // authToken

              webSocketFactory, // webSocketFactory

              new clover.ImageUtil()); // Image Util
};

CloverDeviceConfiguration.prototype = Object.create(clover.WebSocketPairedCloverDeviceConfiguration.prototype);
CloverDeviceConfiguration.prototype.constructor = CloverDeviceConfiguration;

CloverDeviceConfiguration.prototype.onPairingCode = function(pairingCode) {  
    console.log("Pairing code is " + pairingCode);
};

CloverDeviceConfiguration.prototype.onPairingSuccess = function(authToken) {  
    console.log("Pairing succeeded, authToken is " + authToken);
};
var networkConfiguration = new CloverDeviceConfiguration();

var builderConfiguration = {};
builderConfiguration[clover.CloverConnectorFactoryBuilder.FACTORY_VERSION] = clover.CloverConnectorFactoryBuilder.VERSION_12;
var cloverConnectorFactory = clover.CloverConnectorFactoryBuilder.createICloverConnectorFactory(builderConfiguration);

var cloverConnector = cloverConnectorFactory.createICloverConnector(networkConfiguration);

var CloverConnectorListener = function(cloverConnector, progressinfoCallback) {
    clover.remotepay.ICloverConnectorListener.call(this);
    this.cloverConnector = cloverConnector;
    this.progressinfoCallback = progressinfoCallback;
    this.testStarted = false;
};
CloverConnectorListener.prototype = Object.create(clover.remotepay.ICloverConnectorListener.prototype);
CloverConnectorListener.prototype.constructor = CloverConnectorListener;

CloverConnectorListener.prototype.onDeviceReady = function(merchantInfo) {
    console.log("Clover device is ready, initiating sale request...");
    paymentRequest(1000); //Uncomment this code to issue a test payment request.
};

CloverConnectorListener.prototype.onDeviceDisconnected = function(request) {
    log.info(request);
};

CloverConnectorListener.prototype.onDeviceConnected = function(request) {
    log.info(request);
    isConnected = true;
};

//End Clover Device Configuration/Connection Section



/*
 *
 * Sale request section
 *
 */
CloverConnectorListener.prototype.onVerifySignatureRequest = function(request) {
    console.log("Requesting signatiure verification");
    log.info(request);
    this.cloverConnector.acceptSignature(request);
};

CloverConnectorListener.prototype.onConfirmPaymentRequest = function(request) {
    cloverConnector.acceptPayment(request.payment);
};

CloverConnectorListener.prototype.onSaleResponse = function(response) {
    log.info(response);
    cloverConnector.dispose();
    if (!response.getIsSale()) {
        console.error("Response is not a sale!");
        console.error(response);
    } else {
        console.log("Sale successful!");
    }
};

/*
 *
 * End sale request section
 *
 */

toggleConnection();

process.on('exit', function() {
    cloverConnector.dispose();
});

//TODO: Emitter function to prevent program from closing after a single transaction.
```

Comment: How about [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sessions)

Comment: Do you need to save the token long term, or just for the life of the process? What is the security of this token? Should the user be aware of the token? How long is the validity of the token? If I were to see the token, could I log in to the hardware device from another computer? *TL:DR*: What is your threat model? If the threat is weak, storing it in a variable may be just fine. If the threat is important, you will need to mitigate the consequence of it being stolen.